# Android emulator x86 image running error on win8.1

Tags: android, x86, windows-8.1, haxm

I have downloaded newest version of android studio with Lollipop x86 image. I have clicked "Use host GPU" option and installed latest version of HAXM 1.1.0 from Intel website without any error. But when I try to start android emulator, screen is black and I got following errors in log

```
?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of main
12-09 05:52:21.637: I/qemu-props(0): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
12-09 05:52:21.080: W/auditd(926): type=2000 audit(0.0:1): initialized
12-09 05:52:21.180: I/auditd(926): type=1403 audit(0.0:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
12-09 05:52:21.180: W/auditd(926): type=1404 audit(0.0:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
12-09 05:52:21.637: I/qemu-props(0): receiving..
12-09 05:52:21.637: I/qemu-props(0): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=64m
12-09 05:52:21.641: I/qemu-props(0): receiving..
12-09 05:52:21.641: I/qemu-props(0): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=480
12-09 05:52:21.641: I/qemu-props(0): receiving..
12-09 05:52:21.641: I/qemu-props(0): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=0
12-09 05:52:21.642: I/qemu-props(0): receiving..
12-09 05:52:21.642: I/qemu-props(0): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=none
12-09 05:52:21.643: I/qemu-props(0): receiving..
12-09 05:52:21.643: I/qemu-props(0): exiting (4 properties set).
12-09 05:52:21.715: I/installd(0): installd firing up
12-09 05:52:21.761: I/Netd(0): Netd 1.0 starting
12-09 05:52:21.843: I/(0): debuggerd: Dec  6 2014 01:45:08
12-09 05:52:21.942: I/SurfaceFlinger(931): SurfaceFlinger is starting
12-09 05:52:21.944: I/SurfaceFlinger(931): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
12-09 05:52:21.947: D/libEGL(931): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
12-09 05:52:21.947: D/libEGL(931): --------- beginning of system
12-09 05:52:22.021: I/Vold(930): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
12-09 05:52:22.022: D/Vold(930): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
12-09 05:52:22.062: W/DirectVolume(930): Deprecated implied prefix pattern detected, please use '/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0*' instead
12-09 05:52:22.062: D/Vold(930): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
12-09 05:52:22.083: I/lowmemorykiller(928): No kernel memory.pressure_level support (errno=2)
12-09 05:52:22.083: E/lowmemorykiller(928): Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
12-09 05:52:22.160: D/libEGL(931): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-09 05:52:22.857: D/gralloc_goldfish(931): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-09 05:52:22.877: I/mediaserver(942): ServiceManager: 0xb6216d40
12-09 05:52:22.879: I/AudioFlinger(942): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
12-09 05:52:22.882: I/ServiceManager(942): Waiting for service batterystats...
12-09 05:52:22.888: E/SurfaceFlinger(931): hwcomposer module not found
12-09 05:52:22.888: E/SurfaceFlinger(931): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
12-09 05:52:22.888: E/SurfaceFlinger(931): --------- beginning of crash
12-09 05:52:22.888: A/libc(931): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 931 (surfaceflinger)
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:5.0.1/LSX66B/1630668:eng/test-keys'
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): Revision: '0'
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): ABI: 'x86'
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): pid: 931, tid: 931, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
12-09 05:52:23.018: I/DEBUG(939): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
12-09 05:52:23.019: I/DEBUG(939):     eax 00000000  ebx 000003a3  ecx 000003a3  edx 00000006
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     esi b77f9f08  edi 00000002
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     eip b7765d36  ebp 000003a3  esp bf8da910  flags 00000286
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939): backtrace:
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #00 pc 00074d36  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #01 pc 00021b1b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+155)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #02 pc 00023394  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #03 pc 0001b874  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+84)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #04 pc 000303a5  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #05 pc 0001f337  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+199)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #06 pc 000008a1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #07 pc 00012a34  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
12-09 05:52:23.020: I/DEBUG(939):     #08 pc 000009ff  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-09 05:52:23.091: I/DEBUG(939): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
12-09 05:52:23.095: I/ServiceManager(929): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
12-09 05:52:26.144: I/SurfaceFlinger(1061): SurfaceFlinger is starting
12-09 05:52:26.144: I/SurfaceFlinger(1061): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
12-09 05:52:26.144: D/libEGL(1061): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
12-09 05:52:26.144: D/libEGL(1061): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-09 05:52:26.148: I/Netd(1060): Netd 1.0 starting
12-09 05:52:26.204: D/gralloc_goldfish(1061): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-09 05:52:26.204: E/SurfaceFlinger(1061): hwcomposer module not found
12-09 05:52:26.204: E/SurfaceFlinger(1061): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
12-09 05:52:26.204: A/libc(1061): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1061 (surfaceflinger)
12-09 05:52:26.245: I/mediaserver(1062): ServiceManager: 0xb6116d40
12-09 05:52:26.245: I/AudioFlinger(1062): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
12-09 05:52:26.245: I/ServiceManager(1062): Waiting for service batterystats...
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:5.0.1/LSX66B/1630668:eng/test-keys'
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): Revision: '0'
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): ABI: 'x86'
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): pid: 1061, tid: 1061, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
12-09 05:52:26.327: I/DEBUG(939): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     eax 00000000  ebx 00000425  ecx 00000425  edx 00000006
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     esi b7753f08  edi 00000002
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     eip b76bfd36  ebp 00000425  esp bfa71fb0  flags 00000286
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939): backtrace:
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     #00 pc 00074d36  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     #01 pc 00021b1b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+155)
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     #02 pc 00023394  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
12-09 05:52:26.329: I/DEBUG(939):     #03 pc 0001b874  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+84)
12-09 05:52:26.330: I/DEBUG(939):     #04 pc 000303a5  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
12-09 05:52:26.330: I/DEBUG(939):     #05 pc 0001f337  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+199)
12-09 05:52:26.330: I/DEBUG(939):     #06 pc 000008a1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-09 05:52:26.330: I/DEBUG(939):     #07 pc 00012a34  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
12-09 05:52:26.330: I/DEBUG(939):     #08 pc 000009ff  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-09 05:52:26.367: I/DEBUG(939): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
12-09 05:52:26.377: I/ServiceManager(929): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
```

Then these errors repeat and repeat again. I have no idea what's going on here.
I really appreciate if you can help me fix this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Join "black screen" + "Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer." I guess your running a lower version of the API on the Qemu, then the hwcomposer cannot render it even if do not uses GPU. 
Seems your problem is about the hwcomposer GUI features, not the Qemu itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Genymotion](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/) emulator. It runs in virtual box and really fast.

Also, you can get the google service like use play store in that emulator of lollipop, check out [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).

Comment: Since there is official and free emulator, I am not interested in buying another one. Although this is not exactly an answer to my question, thank you very much anyway.